# Why is the last item in recycler view only displayed?

Tags: java, android, json

I create json array in mocki.io and get data from that
when run the  app show the last item in my json array in to the recycler list
just show last item in all of the items in emulator
how to fix that ?

how to get item one from my data and show in zero position in my recycler ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        List<PeopleModel> peopleModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "https://mocki.io/v1/59c9548b-4cde-48d8-9d60-f25444944b81", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                PeopleModel peopleModel = new PeopleModel();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        peopleModel.setFirstName(jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
                        peopleModel.setLastName(jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
                        peopleModel.setId(String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("id")));
                        peopleModel.setCity(jsonObject.getString("city"));
                        peopleModelList.add(peopleModel);

                    }
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,
                            RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new PeopleAdapter(peopleModelList));
                    Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: "+response);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic issue of Object by Reference, note that in your codebase you have created only one object of `PeopleModel peopleModel = new PeopleModel();` and then you are just updating the object's internal value and appending the same object in the List. As a result the List contains the same object reference multiple times and in each loop you are update updating the same object's data.

To fix this, you need a new PeoplerModel for each item in your list, so you need to initiate the peopleModel inside your for loop instead of outside.

```
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        PeopleModel peopleModel = new PeopleModel();

                        peopleModel.setFirstName(jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
                        peopleModel.setLastName(jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
                        peopleModel.setId(String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("id")));
                        peopleModel.setCity(jsonObject.getString("city"));
                        peopleModelList.add(peopleModel);

                    }
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,
                            RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new PeopleAdapter(peopleModelList));
                    Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: "+response);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }
```